# How to use jquery autocomplete to load data from mysql database?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, smarty

I want to make one search box which display list of  matched records from database related to which we have type in our box,
I have Use Jquery's Auto Complete.
That's OK, but I want to select records from my database Table instead manually give it in var availableTags.
I want to get records from DB in var availableTags in following code..

here is my code with Smarty Templates.....

My Html:(searchh.tpl)

```
{block name=head}
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
      <script>

    }   
      $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
          "Python",
          "Ruby",
          "Scala",
          "Scheme"
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
          source: availableTags     
        });
      });

      </script>
    {/block}
    {block name=body}
    <div class="ui-widget">
      <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
      <input id="tags" />
    </div>
    {/block}
```

My php :(searchh.php)

```
<?php 
    include("include/config.inc.php");
    $pArray = 0;
    $search = isset($_POST['search']) && ($_POST["search"] != "") ? $_POST['search']:''; 
    if($search != '')
    {   
      $query="select * from party where partyName like '%$search%' ";
      $result = mysql_query($query);
      $pArray = array();
      $n = 0;
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
      {
        $pArray[$n]['partyId']   = $row['partyId'];
        $pArray[$n]['partyName'] = $row['partyName'];
        $n++;
      }
    }
    include("./bottom.php");
    $smarty->assign("search",$search);
    $smarty->assign("pArray",$pArray);
    $smarty->display('searchh.tpl');
    ?>
```

If Anybody can help, It will very grateful to me.
Thanks..

Comment: Implement that in php and send a ajax request.

Comment: why dont just print all of db records inside availableTags?

Comment: @Charlie I exactly Want To Do That. But Not Manually, I want Records select from db but i don't know about how to store it in Var availableTags.

Answer (score 2):

change your url path like {$smarty.server.PHP_SELF | dirname}.balanceAj.php
and you use get method in ajax function and get data using post method.
If you use get method to send data (for get data $_GET[])
and Post method using (for get data $_post[])

Comment: Thanx Ankit ,But I Exactly Want To Display My Data Of Aj As A AutoComplete & For That I need To Store That In Var availableTags, But I Don't Know HOw To Retrive from Aj & Store In Var in Jquery.

Comment: ok sangna first of this id #partyBalance div blank after, call ajax refresh div automatically change div value. retrive from database.

Comment: I have alredy tried that. but i dont want to display my records ANYWHERE, but Only on autocomplete, in var availableTags . And I think I dont Need Aj for that. i have already my code in php file

Comment: How can i store my php records which i have selected from db in Var availableTags

Comment: using array variable you store all database record

Comment: I have tried that Also, I had put value: "{$pArray[sec].partyName}" in place of  source: availableTags

Answer (score 0):

You have not referenced your php file from the javascript. "remember to point to the exact location of the php file as in the example below"

```
 `$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
              source: "/searchh.php"
            });
```